# Changing polynomial degrees leads to different coefficients in Fuzzy RDD

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, regression-discontinuity

I am running a Fuzzy RDD and I am getting some unusual results, the coefficient of interest changes sign and significance with different polynomial specifications.

When using a linear polynomial with an interaction (to account for a different polynomial on either side of the cut-off) the coefficient is negative and significant, with a quadratic polynomial with an interaction, the coefficient is negative and not statistically significant, and with a cubic polynomial with an interaction it is positive and statistically significant.

I know about the issue of using high order polynomial expansions and how this affects significance, but I was looking for an explanation about how that would affect the sign (direction) of the effect.